# How to use service api class with reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, service

I need to submit an already initialized service to the redux store with reduxjs/toolkit.
How can i do this? Is there a best practice for this case?

```
import { store as reduxStore } from './store';

....

function SomePartAppWithOwnStore({baseUrl= './some-api/layouts/api'}) {
  const config = new Configuration({ basePath: baseUrl});
  const serviceClaimsApi = new ClaimsApi(config);
  
  return (
    <div className="some-part-app">
      <Provider store={reduxStore}>
        <ConfigProvider locale={ruRU}>
          <Router>
            <AppRouter />
          </Router>
        </ConfigProvider>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have a client generated with an openapi generator by swagger.json . I need to initialize it with the correct base url and then use it in the redux store like https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk. The problem is that the base url comes as a props to the react component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
// someSlice.ts
export const createAppReducer = (service: UserApi) => createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk('apiLayoutsUserProfileGet', async (userId, thunkAPI) => await service.getUser(userId))

  actionManager.add(fetchUserById);

  builder.addCase(fetchUserById.pending, (state: any, action) => {
    console.log(state);
    state.userPending = true;
  })

  builder.addCase(fetchUserById.fulfilled, (state: any, action) => {
    state.user = action.payload;
    state.userPending = false;
  })

export const actions = actionManager;
```

```
// store.ts
export const mixInReducers = (service: UserApi) => {
  const appReducer = createAppReducer(service);

  const reducers = combineReducers({
    layout: appReducer
  })

  store.replaceReducer(reducers);
};
```

```
// App.tsx

function App () {
  const user = useAppSelector(selectUser);
  ...
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchUserById());
  }, []);
  ...
}


function AppWrapper() { 

const layoutsApi = new LayoutsApi({basePath:'someapi/'});
....

mixInReducers(layoutsApi);

....

return (
 <Provider store={reduxStore}>
  <App>
 </Provider>
 );
}
```

Maybe someone knows the solution better?